# Play youtube audio only from url in django

Tags: django, url, audio, youtube

So I am making a django app in which you can look up a video by a keyword and you get the url back. I want to play the youtube video on my page. I know I can do that with embed code but I want to play only the audio without the video. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to accomplish this using pytube3's '.url' property of a stream. An example:

```
url=YouTube(url).streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().url
```

Then you can redirect the user to the url in your views.py file like this:

```
return redirect(url)
```

Or you can make it a clickable link by passing it to the template in the context:

```
views.py
context = {'url': url)
return redirect(request, template.html, context)

template.html
<a href="{{ url }}">Click here to play the song</a>
```